# Adicionar um texto em uma determinada posição

Tags: delphi

Olá, preciso adicionar um TEXTO em uma determinada posição de um arquivo TXT, se possível usando o STRING LIST.

Tenho um TXT e dentro desse TXT tem umas 300 linhas. E no meio dele tem a seguinte linha:

```
hardware{98828};
```

Preciso adicionar um TEXTO antes dessa frase ai, como posso fazer ? no caso ele tem que identificar que existe esse TEXTO no arquivo TXT, e adicionar uma palavra antes dela.

Aguardo qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode ir lendo o arquivo linha a linha e guardando em um StringList, como você comentou e ir verificando se existe essa "string" nesta linha com o Pos(), por exemplo:

```
int posicao = Pos(textoDesejado, linha);

if(posicao > 0) { } // encontrou o textoDesejado...
```

caso encontre é possível editar o texto utilizando Copy(), por exemplo:

```
linha = Copy(linha, 1, posicao) + outroTextoAdicionado + Copy(linha, posicao + 1, Length(linha));
```

E após colocar a linha no StringList... E assim até terminar de ler todo o arquivo txt.